# How do I re-add a file to my git repo that was previously being ignored and won't show up now?

Tags: git, .htaccess, git-tower

I originally had .htaccess on my exclude list for my Git repository.  I've removed it from the exclude list now (and double checked it's off the ignore list too).

I changed the file locally, but Tower (my git client) isn't showing the file as changed and ready to be committed remotely.

How do I get Tower to recognize that the file is changed and available for commit?

Comment: Was it ever added to the repo? I.e. `git add <my file>`

Comment: Yes. I had it added originally and added it to Exclude so it wouldn't overwrite the version already up in my remote.  Now I want to overwrite the remote version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the file with the -f flag:

```
    git add -f .htaccess
```

Comment: From screenshots i`ve seen, there is a Terminal button in the menubar. Try to enter it there.

Comment: I tried adding the file via Terminal to my repository but no dice - the file still isn't appearing in Tower ready to commit. :(

Comment: Figured it out.  Removed the file completely from the repo then re-added.  Thanks!